# Liferay Faces and remote javascript inside head

Tags: liferay-6, jsf-2.2

I am developing a Liferay Primefaces portlet using Primefaces 6.0 and Liferay 6.2.5 tomcat bundle. I was using the old versioning scheme of Liferay Faces.

And then i decided to switch to the current versions as seen [here](http://liferayfaces.org/) for 6.2, 2.2, primefaces and maven.

My problem is that i had some portlets using the primefaces [gmap](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/basic.xhtml) component, so i needed to include the google maps javascript, and i did it with the follow piece of code:

```
    <h:head>
        <script
            src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"
            type="text/javascript" />
    </h:head>
```

Even though this worked perfectly before, after my upgrade it doesn't work. In fact, i can't include any script using the code above. Any help/workarounds to include a remote javascript inside the head tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit: [FACES-2974](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2974) has been fixed in Bridge Impl `4.1.0`.

This is a [regression bug (FACES-2974)](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2974) in Liferay Faces Bridge `4.0.0` (and `3.0.0` and `2.0.0`).

To workaround this issue, you can create a composite component with a `name` attribute. The name must end in either "`css`" or "`js`" and should probably be unique per view to ensure that it is always loaded. For example, create the following **`resources/workaround/headElements.xhtml`** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd">

    <!-- Workaround for https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2974 -->
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="name" required="true" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </cc:implementation>

</ui:component>
```

To use this component with the google maps script mentioned above:

```
<h:head>
    <workaround:headElements name="#{view.viewId}.js">
        <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"
        type="text/javascript" /></script>
    </workaround:headElements>
    <!-- ... -->
</h:head>
```

Comment: Cool workaround, thanks for the assistance.
Edit: With this workaround, will the bridge still not load the script more than one times if, for example, i add two portlets that contain the above code? (I know that gmap is functional only alone, just out of curiosity)

Comment: I think it will still deduplicate the script ([thanks to these lines of `HeadResource`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces-bridge-ext/blob/3.0.0/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/bridge/ext/event/internal/HeadResource.java#L84-L85)). Can you try it and report back?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. The workaround indeed correctly places the script inside the head, and no more than once in case of multiple instances of a portlet. Also, even though it's obvious for you that the component should be placed inside the h:head element, I think you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: @ΟδυσσέαςΔούμας, edited, thanks! Can you upvote my answer?